# Reading Parameter values which contain # in url instead of?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

How to read parameter values from the below URL in Java. In the url instead of `?` `#` is being used. This is the redirect URL which I got from vk.com site.

http://sampleclient.com/vkclient/showAccessToken.jsp#access_token=361d617f92db608a78dab95604c6553&expires_in=86400&user_id=1234

I tried using below approach; but it doesn't work.

```
HttpServeletRequest request;
String token=request.getParameter("access_token");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't! Those parameters are only visible in browser